# Understanding Pyplot code for coloured scatter plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, scatter-plot

I'm working in Python and am a total beginner in plotting things. In another post ([matplotlib Plot multiple scatter plots, each colored by different thrid variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201356/matplotlib-plot-multiple-scatter-plots-each-colored-by-different-thrid-variable))

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

jet=plt.get_cmap('coolwarm')

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1,2,3,4]
z = [1,1,1,1]

a = [2,3,4,5]
b = [1,2,3,4]
c = [2,2,2,2]

d = [3,4,5,6]
e = [1,2,3,4]
f = [3,3,3,3]

plt.scatter(x, y, s=100, c=z, cmap=jet, vmin=0, vmax=4)
plt.scatter(a, b, s=100, c=c, cmap=jet, vmin=0, vmax=4)
plt.scatter(d, e, s=100, c=f, cmap=jet, vmin=0, vmax=4)

plt.clim(0,5)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I've found this code and it actually already fits pretty well for my purpose. It produces 3 scatter plots with different colours: [image]

I now want to change the code to be able to take up 10 different plots instead of 3, all with different colours, but I don't really understand the code. Can someone explain what the different parts of the scatter command do (and also plt.clim()). I searched online but it was all pretty chaotic. Also I found some nicer colour sceme called YIGnBu but the program doesn't accept it.

Maybe someone can shed a little light on this for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let's break down the `scatter` command: `plt.scatter(x, y, s=100, c=z, cmap=jet, vmin=0, vmax=4)`. The `x,y` are your points of course. `s=100` is the size of the symbol. `c=z` is the colour to use. Note that this can just be a scalar, or even a name (c='red'). `cmap=jet` sets the colour map to be used, so that your numbers are mapped to a colour. `vmin, vmax` set the upper and lower limits of the colour range. `plt.clim()` is setting the limits for the colour bar - which would have been from 0 to 4 (data limits) in this case, but are forced to be 0 to 5 instead. Hope that helps!

Comment: @VBB please don't provide an answer as a comment. Use the answer field below to provide an answer.

Comment: Concerning the colormap, it's called `YlGnBu` instead of `YIGnBu`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - noted. I didn't want to provide sample code, but didn't want to say RTFM either... thought giving this as an answer would be overkill.

Comment: @VBB Thanks, this cleared it up a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it helps to read the [scatter documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html). This is not chaotic and explains every part of the `scatter` signature.

Second there are examples on the matplotlib page, e.g.

- [scatter_star_poly](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_star_poly.html)
- [scatter_demo](https://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html)

which might be better suited as a resource.

In general, the idea of a scatter plot is that different points of the scatter can have different sizes (which are determined by the `s` argument) and colors (determined by `c`).

The example code you show is thus not a very good example, as it uses three different scatter plots, where only a single plot is needed

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4, 2,3,4,5, 3,4,5,6]
y = [1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4]
z = [1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3]

plt.scatter(x, y, s=100, c=z, cmap='YlGnBu')

plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

To create 10 different plots you may equally use a normal [`plot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,5)
y = np.arange(1,5)

for i in range(10):
    plt.plot(x+i, y, ls="", marker="o", ms=10, color=plt.cm.YlGnBu(i/9.) )
plt.show()
```

[image]

However this last approach will become a little more complicated when adding a colorbar, since the plot itself is not a ScalarMappable itself. Once therefore needs to create the ScalarMappable for the colorbar manually.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,5)
y = np.arange(1,5)

for i in range(10):
    plt.plot(x+i, y, ls="", marker="o", ms=10, color=plt.cm.YlGnBu(i/9.) )

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="YlGnBu", norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=9))
sm.set_array([])  # only needed for matplotlib < 3.1
plt.colorbar(sm)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explain how i can change the YlGnBu to other colour scemes, (the lightest colour can't really be seen on my display i need something else). Do you maybe have a reccomendation for a sceme  that discerns clearly between different colours and can also be seen good

Comment: You may refer to the [colormaps reference](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) and choose the colormap that best suits. I cannot recommend anything as I don't know the desired application.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, it works now. One last question: I used your second way, using plt.plot. Is there a way to also display a colorbar in this case? (when i use colobar as in the example with the scatter plot the program gives me an error

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution including colorbar.